# socketio video streaming

Tags: api, node.js, webkit, socket.io

Currently i have a node.js and socket.io application in development on my local machine to test out a few new web technologies and apis.

Currently i have a user being able to log in to my application and display their webcam stream on the page in a html5 video element.  Now the source of that element is something like this:

```
<video id="self" autoplay="" style="display: inline; " src="blob:http%3A//192.168.1.20%3A1234/29768571-e561-4b28-9ebe-bf53d2ee13ad"></video>
```

I have enabled other users who join the application request to view their stream, so i am passing them the **blob:http%3A//192.168.1.20%3A1234/29768571-e561-4b28-9ebe-bf53d2ee13ad** portion of the streaming user.  Now in testing so far on my local network, that second user is getting a 404 error on the blob.  Is there something i am missing?  also will socket.io be able to keep that stream constantly streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass BLOB's address to other client, that address you have is specific to that page. You should send the content of video, not the address.

Comment: is it possible to send the byte data of the video through socket.io?

Comment: There is a binary specification on WebSockets but not sure about it. You can convert the data to base64 format, it will be portable